# Javascript Cookie to expire each Tuesday

Tags: javascript, datetime, cookies

I have a cookie that expires in 7 days after the user has submitted a form.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + 604800); // 7 days
```

..etc

However, I want the cookie to expire every Monday idepedently of when the user submitted the form.

Any idea?

Best,
Christina

Comment: just subtract the number of days.

Comment: you might simply calculate the expiry time based on the current time, after determining the current time's weekday. Also, please have a look at the [tour]. As it stands, your question might get deleted soon.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add days to the current date like so:

```
var date = new Date();

var dateNextMonday = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 8 - date.getDay());
var nextMonday = new Date(dateNextMonday);
console.log(nextMonday);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awj5sbpg/